# UEFI firmware not recgonising GPT partition table

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi

The UEFI firmware of my ASRock FM2A75 Pro4, fails to recognise the GPT partition tables of my SATA harddisks, as shown by the `map` EFI shell command:

```
Device mapping table
  fs0     :Removable HardDisk - Alias hd15f0b blk0 
           PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x13,0x2)/USB(0x5,0x0)/HD(1,MBR,0x599b0b48,0x800,0x771800)
  blk0    :Removable HardDisk - Alias hd15f0b fs0 
           PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x13,0x2)/USB(0x5,0x0)/HD(1,MBR,0x599b0b48,0x800,0x771800)
  blk1    :HardDisk - Alias (null)
           PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x11,0x0)/Sata(0x1,0x0)/HD(1,MBR,0x00000000,0x1,0xffffffff)
  blk2    :HardDisk - Alias (null)
           PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x11,0x0)/Sata(0x2,0x0)/HD(1,MBR,0x00000000,0x1,0xffffffff)
  blk3    :BlockDevice - Alias (null)
           PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x11,0x0)/Sata(0x0,0x0)
  blk4    :BlockDevice - Alias (null)
           PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x11,0x0)/Sata(0x1,0x0)
  blk5    :BlockDevice - Alias (null)
           PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x11,0x0)/Sata(0x2,0x0)
  blk6    :Removable BlockDevice - Alias (null)
           PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x13,0x2)/USB(0x5,0x0)
  hd15f0b :Removable HardDisk - Alias fs0 blk0 
           PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x13,0x2)/USB(0x5,0x0)/HD(1,MBR,0x599b0b48,0x800,0x771800)
```

A dump of the beginning of the first disk is:

```
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001c0  01 00 ee fe ff ff 01 00  00 00 ff ff ff ff 00 00  |................|
000001d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200  45 46 49 20 50 41 52 54  00 00 01 00 00 02 00 00  |EFI PART........|
00000210  fc 8c f5 67 00 00 00 00  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |...g............|
00000220  af d9 30 46 02 00 00 00  00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..0F............|
00000230  8e d9 30 46 02 00 00 00  4d a7 05 30 c3 6b 10 4a  |..0F....M..0.k.J|
00000240  b3 de d9 8b 01 7f bd 45  02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.......E........|
00000250  80 00 00 00 80 00 00 00  e2 cd 84 66 00 00 00 00  |...........f....|
00000260  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000400  28 73 2a c1 1f f8 d2 11  ba 4b 00 a0 c9 3e c9 3b  |(s*......K...>.;|
00000410  f2 68 35 6f f8 53 5f 40  b4 91 e5 eb e1 76 6a f9  |.h5o.S_@.....vj.|
00000420  00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00  ff 27 03 00 00 00 00 00  |.........'......|
00000430  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000480  79 d3 d6 e6 07 f5 c2 44  a2 3c 23 8f 2a 3d f9 28  |y......D.<#.*=.(|
00000490  ea e7 0d a6 47 50 84 48  ab 8a 73 3e b3 99 e3 a8  |....GP.H..s>....|
000004a0  00 28 03 00 00 00 00 00  8e d9 30 46 02 00 00 00  |.(........0F....|
000004b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00100000  eb 3c 90 6d 6b 66 73 2e  66 61 74 00 02 04 01 00  |.<.mkfs.fat.....|
```

The disks were partitioned with cfdisk from util-linux and work fine with Linux.

The output `sgdisk -v /dev/sda` is:

```
No problems found. 0 free sectors (0 bytes) available in 0
segments, the largest of which is 0 (0 bytes) in size.
```

Comment: What does `sgdisk -v /dev/sda` (or whatever the disk device is) show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After comparing behaviour with that with parted that I used previously, it appears the buggy UEFI rejects partition tables with a header length of 512, which the standard permits:

> Size in bytes of the GPT Header. The
>   HeaderSize must be greater than or
>   equal to 92 and must be less than or equal to
>   the logical block size.

After modifying util-linux to use a header size of 92 and recreating my partitions with fdisk UEFI now recognises my partitions.

Answer (score 0):

It is "fixed" in recent util-linux (as of 2.26-rc1):

> Kay reported that Windows 8.1 installed does not recognize GPT created
>   by libfdisk, but parted works as expected.
>
> It seems (according to the header hexdump) that the problem is
>   HeaderSize GPT field where libfdisk uses 512 (header + reserved area),
>   but parted uses 92. The both is pretty valid according to the current
>   EFI standard, but 92 is probably more backwardly compatible.
>
> I also found places in code where libfdisk gpt driver is inconsistent
>   and uses sometimes all sector and simetimes sizeof(gpt_header) only.
>   The right solution is to read all sector (into zeroized memory) and
>   later write again all sector to the device.

[libfdisk: (gpt) cleanup header size usage](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/commit/4bb82a455461e42644c9b3d8aa1206ad8889ed35)